# Anchor tag stripped from URL on form submit

Tags: jquery, expressionengine, zurb-foundation

Freeform version: 4.07
ExpressionEngine v2.5.3 - Build Date: 20120911

I have a freeform form inside a jQuery tab. When the form is submitted with erros, the anchor for that tab is stripped from the URL. This takes me back to the first tab and not the tab with the form in. Is there a way to redirect the user back to the form tab?

Thanks

```
<li id="qaTab">
  {exp:freeform:form
  form_id="2"
  required="name|email|user_message"
  return="contact_us/thank_you"
  recipients="yes"
  recipient1="Happy Harry|h_harry@somemail.com"
  recipient2="Lazy Larry|lazyl63@somemail.com"
  recipient_template="contact_form"
  notify_user="yes"
  user_email_field="user_email"
  inline_errors="yes"
  }
   {if freeform:general_errors}
    <h2>There were some error(s) with your submission:</h2>
   <ul>
   {freeform:general_errors}
    <li>{freeform:error_message}</li>
   {/freeform:general_errors}
   </ul>
   {/if}
   <div class="row">
    <div class="six columns">
     <label>{freeform:label:name}</label>
     {freeform:field:name}
     {if freeform:error:name}<small class="error">{freeform:error:name}</small>{/if}
    </div>
    <div class="six columns">
     <label>{freeform:label:email}</label>
     {freeform:field:email}
     {if freeform:error:email}<small class="error">{freeform:error:email}</small>{/if}
    </div>
   </div>
   {freeform:label:user_message}
   {freeform:field:user_message}
   {if freeform:error:user_message}
   <small class="error">{freeform:error:user_message}</small>{/if}
   <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="{title}" id="subject">
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" class="button">
  {/exp:freeform:form}
 </li>
```

Answer (score 5):

You should solve this using jQuery by:

1. Checking for the existence of class error
2. If exists: open the tab with the form
3. Else: do nothing

Which would be something like:

```
if ($(".error").length > 0) {  
    $("#tabs").tabs("select", "#qaTab");
}
```

Good luck!